# Adding up values from array elements in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have done some aggregation to arrive at the below document structure for my given data:

```
{ 
"_id" : "test", 
"NoOfQuestions" : 3.0, 
"info" : [
    {
        "AnswerrCount" : 3
    }, 
    {
        "AnswerrCount" : 3
    }, 
    {
        "AnswerrCount" : 2
    }
]
}
```

However, I am trying to add up all the values in the `AnswerrCount` column. So from the above example, I want another column that says `TotalAnswers:8, (3+3+2)` and then eventually have a from using the `NoOfQuestions`, `FinalTotal:11, (8+3)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [**`$sum`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/) aggregation to add array values

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$addFields": {
    "TotalAnswers": {
      "$sum": "$info.AnswerrCount"
    },
    "FinalTotal": {
      "$add": [{ "$sum": "$info.AnswerrCount" }, "$NoOfQuestions"]
    }
  }}
])
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, it works. However, can you please help me out with the Update??

Comment: Ok but it will be better if you ask a new question so that I can easily explain you.

Answer (score 0):

```
db.collection.aggregate([{
    $unwind: "$info"
}, {
    $group: {
        _id: null,
        TotalAnswers: {
            $sum: '$info.AnswerrCount'
        },
        doc: {
            $first: '$$CURRENT'
        }
    }
}, {
    $project: {
        TotalAnswers: 1,
        FinalTotal: {
            '$add': ['$TotalAnswers', '$doc.NoOfQuestions']
        },
        _id: 0
    }
}])
```